# multiple iteration in a single for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have,

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [7, 8, 9, 14, 25, 36]
list3 = [43, 65]
```

and what i want to achieve is

```
1 7 43
2 8 65
3 9
4 14
5 25
  36
```

i have tried looking in methods like `itertools` and `multiprocessiong`but none of them helps,

is there a way i can achiver this in a single for loop like...

```
for I, J, K inb list1, list2, list3:
    print('{} {} {}'.format(I, J, K))
```

any help?

**EDIT**

zip function gets the least number of elements from the lists, if i use zip the output will be

```
1 7 43
2 8 65
```

Comment: Oh look, the top answer uses a function from `itertools`!

Comment: You want the zip longest function

Comment: but it returns none when one of them is exausted

Comment: Looks at `itertools.izip_longest`

Comment: @jadsq  it returns none when one of them is done!, even though i can use conditional statement to avoid it but in the cases of large data entries conditionals are not preferable in my opinion

Comment: *Please* read the linked page. You can set `fillvalue` to some other value.

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: print(" ".join(map(str,x))),zip_longest(list1,list2,list3,fillvalue='')))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using itertools:

```
import itertools

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [7, 8, 9, 14, 25, 36]
list3 = [43, 65]

for a, b, c in itertools.izip_longest(list1, list2, list3):
     print a, b, c
```